# How to remove .html extension to static website in google cloud bucket

Tags: html, .htaccess, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is there any way to remove the .htlm extension from a static website located in a google cloud storage bucket? I tried using .htaccess but it didn't work.

Comment: Configuration by an `.htaccess` file is an Apache-specific concept. Google Cloud Storage Buckets (to my knowledge) do not serve files using Apache (or any derivation of it thereof).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, but you can use [App engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website) or [Firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) to serve an static HTML website and hide `HTML` extension.

For the App Engine approach you can manually add URLs on the app.yaml for example

```
 url: /contact
  static_files: www/contact.html
  upload: www/contact.html
```

Comment: I figured out, thaks for answering!