# Google Cloud HTTPS Load Balancer URL Rewrite To Remove .html Extension

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

I've read the [Traffic management overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/traffic-management-global) for global external HTTP(S) load balancers [URL maps overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts) but do not see how to do the following:

`https://example.com/page ----> https://example.com/page.html`

Is it possible to "remove" the .html extension from my URL with Google's global external HTTP(S) load balancer?

My website is hosted on Google Cloud Storage (bucket). I understand that I can use `gsutil` to set metadata on files to `type:text/html` and that is a viable workaround, however I would need to script that and I spent a couple of hours looking at that but never got it figured out. The script would basically need to recursively list all files with `.html` extension then rename them removing the file extension then set the metadata.

Comment: How is your website hosted? What GCP Products are you using? Kindly update your question with further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[URL rewrites](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/traffic-management#redirects) allow you to present external users with URLs that are different from the URLs that your services use. Although it says that it `provides URL shortening`, extension removal isn't done through the Load Balancer, but rather by [setting the file's Content-Type metadata to "text/html"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936791/how-to-remove-html-extensions-from-google-cloud-platform-url) or using [App engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website) or [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) hosting to serve a static HTML website and hide HTML extension. The latter suggestion was discussed in another stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194440/how-to-remove-html-extension-to-static-website-in-google-cloud-bucket)

```
 url: /contact
  static_files: www/contact.html
  upload: www/contact.html
```

Comment: Right. I abandoned Cloud Storage for hosting static files, and switched over to App Engine running Node/Express. Cloud Storage works fine for static hosting as long as you don't have subdirectories.